# scipy curve_fit returns error for keyword absolute_sigma

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on python 2.7 with numpy version 1.8.1 and scipy version 0.13.3. When I do a `curve_fit` with the keyword `absolute_sigma=True`, I get the message:

> TypeError: leastsq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'absolute_sigma'

I updated numpy and scipy to the versions mentioned above as the keyword `absolute_sigma` seems to be a new feature. However, no success!

any ideas how to solve this issue? Do I need scipy 0.14... ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `absolute_sigma` parameter was added in version 0.14. Compare the call signatures:

- [version 0.14](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)
- [version 0.13](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)